# How can I remove a node from a firebase realtime database when the app exits

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

When my app crashes or the user closes the app I want a particular node to be deleted from the
real-time database.
So, far I am not able to find any way to handle this issue. Could you please point out any reference material or anything of value that can help me implement this? Here I want the `availableDrivers` to be removed but for that, I need to find the state of the app, how is it done? I want to do this from the app itself and not from the functions that firebase / google services (cloud functions etc..)
The scenarios of the app can be like

1. minimized
2. force closed
3. phone dies
4. no internet etc..

[image]

Comment: When to user closes the app - Minimises? or closes it completely?

Comment: minimize or completely both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is the purpose of Firebase's `onDisconnect` method. This this method you can register an operation while you *are* connected to the database backend, which is then executed once the backend notices that the connection is gone.

A simple example:

```
// Somewhere in your application, trigger that the user is online:
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/123/status");
await ref.set(true);
// And after;
// Create an OnDisconnect instance for your ref and set to false,
// the Firebase backend will then only set the value on your ref to false
// when your client goes offline.
OnDisconnect onDisconnect = ref.onDisconnect();
await onDisconnect.set(false);
```

The `onDisconnect` can be triggered either through a clean disconnect, where the client informs the server it is about to disconnect, or through a dirty disconnect, where the client simply stops communicating with the server (for example in the case of a crash, or an actual loss of the physical connection). In the latter case, it may take up to a few minutes before the server detects that the client is gone, and thus runs the `onDisconnect` handlers for that client.

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [offline capabilities](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage#offline-capabilities).

Comment: This is what confuses me, my app has been forced closed, it has no time to execute the `onDisconnect` method, how is the communication established? Or, does firebase takes the `onDisconnect` method in its record and can execute the code on its own even if my app has died or sth?

Comment: Firebase indeed tracks the `onDisconnect` handlers that you registered on its servers, and then executes them when the app has disconnected. I recommend trying it, as it's quite interesting to see your database get modified some time after the client has disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

There's no 100% reliable way of executing code (especially network calls) "when the app exits". What if phone's battery just dies, app crashes or is force closed?

One way to overcome this is remodelling your documents so that instead of removing them, they contain a "last active" timestamp. This timestamp is bumped periodically when the app is active. When timestamp is less than this period from now, document can be considered "inactive" so you query with `.where("lastActiveTimestamp", ">=", Date.now() - period)` (pseudocode). You can also write a firebase function to cleanup inactive documents to optimise the db.

Comment: Will this work when the app is forced closed ?

Comment: This will work if app, for any reason, won't update it's `lastActiveTimestamp` in time.