# Flutter/Firebase real time chat

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello I am developing mobile app with Flutter.

I implemented chat in my app.

```
class ChatRoom {
  ChatRoom({
    required this.chatRoomId,
    required this.chatRoomName,
    required this.createdDate,
    required this.joinedUserList,
    required this.latestMessageID,
    required this.isPositionChatRoom,
    required this.latestMessageTime,
    required this.chatRoomPriority,
    required this.isCustomGroupChat,
  });
  final bool? isCustomGroupChat;
  final int? chatRoomPriority;
  final String? chatRoomId;
  final String? chatRoomName;
  final DateTime? createdDate;
  final String? latestMessageID;
  final DateTime? latestMessageTime;
  final bool? isPositionChatRoom;
  final Map<String, bool>? joinedUserList;
```

This is the part of chat room class.

My question is , I just want to implement if the user in the chatroom.

basically what I am trying to do is,
in joinedUserList

it is `<UserId,bool>`.   if the user is in the chat room I mean ,they enter the chat room

I set the value `${userId} : true`. and when they exit the chat room I set the value as a false.

but the problem is , if they close the app in the chat room, there is no way to set the value as false.

If they press backward button I can set it as false.

So my question is, I am just wondering if there is any function that will be executed when close app in Flutter.

Thanks for reading - I am waiting for your help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking for Firebase's `onDisconnect` handlers, which you register when the app runs, but that then run on the server when it detects that the client is gone. I just gave an answer about how to use them in Flutter, so I recommend checking that out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70741890/how-can-i-remove-a-node-from-a-firebase-realtime-database-when-the-app-exits/70744163?noredirect=1#comment125085718_70744163